# How to add background/highlight to call attention to the selected field in time picker input in Android ..?

Tags: android, material-design-3

I have used time picker from material design 3 :-
https://m3.material.io/components/time-pickers/specs#e1dd4084-e5ff-45e3-8932-42ea605549b4
When I toggle the time picker from dial to input mode the selected field is not getting highlighted, here in the document they have mentioned attribute as :-  "Surface Container Highest" but while adding this item name in style it's giving error as "Cannot resolve symbol"

What is the attribute/item name should I add in the styles to get Expected output :- [In these image the selected item is highlighted with light green background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRjbz.png)

[This is what I have currently achieved but failed in adding highlight to selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in30b.png)

I tried adding the below attribute but it is not available

`<item name="colorSurfaceContainerHighest">@color/orange </item>`